# Ошибка Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть такой код:

```
"SELECT *  
FROM  orders 
LEFT JOIN shops ON orders.id  = shops.shop_id
WHERE shops.user_id  = '".$this->session->userdata("user_id")."'
GROUP BY orders.id ");
```

Получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'cod_db.shops.inc_id' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Запрос абсолютно бессмысленный. Потому как он возьмёт запись из orders и присоединит к ней одну СЛУЧАЙНУЮ запись из всех соответствующих условиям связывания и отбора из таблицы shops.

Comment: А причину ошибки тебе написали открытым текстом: _this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by_

Comment: @Akina запрос не является бессмысленным, если одному заказу соответствует лишь один магазин, что довольно разумно (как правило, так и бывает).

Comment: @cheops Либо этот тезис подкреплён структурой (соотв. констрейнт в DDL), либо он ошибочен.

Comment: Кто и зачем плюсует этот вопрос? Это же элементарный SQL и GROUP BY

Answer (score 3):

Вместо * перечислите те поля, которые хотите видеть в запросе, и отдельно укажите те, по которым хотите группировать.

Comment: _SELECT * не может упоминаться при GROUP BY._ Это неверное утверждение в случае MySQL.

Comment: Может, если не включен режим sql_mode=only_full_group_by